# Not able to use secrets.json in my C# app

Tags: c#

I have installed and have a secrets.json file that was created for me. That file has information like

```
{
  "appKey": "boboc302-bfcc-4cea-b8a8-9df900afbobo",
  "appSecret": "bobocc8f-c5f2-482e-9e10-955aacf3bobo",
  "appID": "boboa849-dd9b-4c21-8492-10fa6749bobo",
  "jobID": "bobo67bf-c6f3-4759-a0e2-7e8c75d3bobo",
}
```

Since my app does use CreateDefaultBuilder, I updated the class to use these as

```
using MSStuff.Graph;
using MSStuff.Identity.Client;

namespace OurClassWorker.Auth
{
    internal class AuthenticationProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
    {
        private ILogger<AuthenticationProvider> _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration ourAppSecrets;

        public string appKey { get; private set; }

        public AuthenticationProvider(ILogger<AuthenticationProvider> logger, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            ourAppSecrets = config;
        }

        public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            try
            {
                var whateve = ourAppSecrets.GetValue<string>("appKey"); //null
                var thisway = ourAppSecrets["appKey"]; //null
                var onemore = this.ourAppSecrets["appKey"]; //null
                var okreallylast = this.ourAppSecrets.GetValue<string>("appKey"); //null
        ................
        Additional code that would use the variables
        ................
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(typeof(AuthenticationProvider).Name, "AuthenticateRequestAsync", ex);
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And every test variable is null
What am I doing wrong?

I used several examples from web
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-user-secrets-getting-started/
https://auth0.com/blog/secret-management-in-dotnet-applications/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=windows

to name just a few
I am expecting the values I saved in the secrets.json to be returned

Comment: Maybe ```config``` is not what you expect it to be?

Comment: You need to show us how you are reading the JSON into the program or we can’t help you.